# Function that has potential to increase current value, based on current value

Tags: functions

Math is not my strong suit, let's start there. (Be gentle.) I have a game engine that is "ticking" every 1 second. I would like for a number, `A`, to increase at an exponential decaying rate based on a function of its current value. (Up to a maximum value that would be hit after a *long* time, potentially.)

As an example, with an initial value of `10` and a maximum value of `100`, at "Tick 0" it would have a value of 10.

Then at "Tick 100" it would have a value of `20`. At "Tick 1000", maybe a value of `27`. etc.

The issue is, it can't be dependent on the tick value. It's a property that can be "used up", and then will recover over time - quickly in the beginning, but more slowly as time goes on. So you may be left with a value of `10` at "Tick 4,300,000". I would like for the value to again be `20` at "Tick 4,300,100".

The idea is that this value will be used to determine whether an action can be performed. So for simple actions, it won't really dent. But you can *save up* for more complex actions that might require `30` units, and you'd have to wait for an hour or so.

I've tried a few simple tactics that are close but not quite:

1. The value is "staggered" so that if it's `0 <= A <= 10`, it increases per Tick, and if it's `11 <= A <= 20` it increases every 10 Ticks, etc. but I dislike the plateau effect that occurs.
2. I've tried using a modulus based on `TickCount % (A^2) == 0`, but this does not decay fast enough. Using `A^3`, it decays too quickly at lower values.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding each tick (max value-current value)/100, or whatever divisor makes you happy?  Then subtract however much is used up in the current action.